# Increase the size of C drive

Tags: windows

Can I increase the size of C drive without the help any third-party software?

Comment: Please be a little more specific: Is your entire hard disk larger than the C:\ drive and is it currently partitioned into other volumes (i.e. D:\ E:\ etc)? How large is your C:\ drive and how large is your entire disk?

Answer (score 1):

**In Windows Vista and Windows 7**

> You require no 3rd party software to
>   re-size partitions. For a good guide on
>   how to do it in Windows Vista or 7 go
>   here
>   http://www.winvistaclub.com/t11.html

**If you are using windows XP then you might need to use 3rd party software . Some of them are free**

> - Dr.Freeware Boot CD (also has file recovery, disk imaging and cloning)
> - EASEUS Partition Master (Vista-compatible)
> - Paragon Partition Manager 8.5-- PPM Special Edition serial and free
>     registration
> - CloneZilla GParted LiveCD (Complete partitioning and drive
>     imaging/restoration tools)
> - SystemRescueCD
> - Gparted LiveCD
> - Parted Magic   Vista Recovery Disk (Shrink, expand, create, delete
>     partitions)
> - XP Recovery Console CD image (Create and delete partitions with
>     diskpart.exe)

Answer (score 0):

In Vista and Windows 7 you can, assuming there's free space after the partition. Just use the Disk Management utility in Computer Management.